# Specific entry of inverse of large matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, inverse

Given a large (say 10x10) sparse Hermitian matrix with symbolic entries, I need four specific entries of the inverse matrix. It seems wasteful to me to compute 100 entries of which I only need a few in the end.

Is there a way to compute a small number of specific entries of the inverse matrix that is significantly more efficient than finding the inverse matrix and then extracting the elements?

Here's an example. N is half the dimension of the matrix. For N = 8, inverting takes 51 seconds on my university's computer, and we would ideally like to reach much larger N.

```
A = Table[If[Abs[i - j] == 1, (j - i) a, 0], {i, #}, {j, #}] &;
B = Table[If[Abs[i - j] == 1, b, 0], {i, #}, {j, #}] &;

σ1[N_] := B@N + Table[
    If[Abs[i - j] == 0, 2 μ, 0] + If[i == j == 1, -x, 0] + 
     If[i == j == N, -x, 0]
    , {i, N}, {j, N}];
σ2[N_] := -B@N + Table[
    +If[i == j == 1, -y, 0] + If[i == j == N, -y, 0]
    , {i, N}, {j, N}];

(* Elements of M *)
el[N_, i_, j_] := Which[i <= N && j <= N,
  σ1[N][[i, j]], i > N && j > N,
  σ2[N][[i - N, j - N]], i > N && j <= N,
  A[N][[i - N, j]], i <= N && j > N,
  -A[N][[i, j - N]]] 

M[N_] := Table[el[N, i, j], {i, 2 N}, {j, 2 N}];
```

Daniel Lichtblau's idea `LinearSolve[M@8,UnitVector[16,8]]` takes 4.1 seconds, so it is certainly much faster than inverting the entire matrix, even if it has to be done seperately for each entry.

Comment: If you have *ACM* access, search for *Lin Lin* et al *SelInv* paper.

Comment: As it is stated, the Q is off-topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Mathematica.

Comment: @bobthechemist I have to disagree here. It is clear that you can do an `Inverse` matrix calculation in Mathematica, and checking to see whether a fast version of `Inverse[m][[{3,4},{2,1}]]` exists is not unreasonable. It can be very advantageous. Many functions in Mathematica can be 'cut-off' to stop early and give a restricted set of solutions. Take, for instance, `Ordering` or `Position`.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Your point is taken, and perhaps my choice of closing options was incorrect.  As currently written, anyone willing to answer needs to provide their own MWE, and I think it would benefit the question if the OP provides this example on his/her own.

Comment: `LinearSolve[mat,ej]` will give the jth column only of the inverse, when ej is the jth coordinate axis unit vector. I would expect that to be 2-3 times faster than using `Inverse`.

Comment: For multiple right hand sides, maybe do 'LinearSolve[mat]' and use the resulting 'LinearSolveFunction' on different vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_inverse, the lines below avoid calculating more than needed (less than 1 sec on M[8]):

```
Cofactor[mat_,i_,j_]/;(And@@Thread[{i,j}<=Dimensions[mat]]):=(-1)^(i+j)*Det[Drop[#,{j}]&/@Drop[mat,{i}]];   
inverseElement[mat_, i_,  j_] /; (And @@ Thread[{i, j} <= Dimensions[mat]]) := 
 Cofactor[mat, j, i]/Det[mat];
```